# How to exclude objects when importing a python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Suppose this package which contains only one module:

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty. The module `mymodule.py` is as follows:

```
from math import pi

def two_pi():
    return 2 * pi
```

This is the content of `mymodule`:

```
>>> from mypackage import mymodule
>>> dir(mymodule)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'pi', 'two_pi']
```

The object `pi` is present when I import the module, but I don't want it to be there.

How can I avoid `pi` from being present in `mymodule`?

I have tried defining `__all__ = ['tow_pi']`, however this only works when importing with `from mypackage.mymodule import *`.

Comment: `two_pi`? Consider [tau](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(angle)#Tau_proposals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to hide `pi` from `mymodule` because it is simply part of the module's global namespace, an attribute of the module object.

A workaround is to import `pi` locally instead in `mymodule.py`:

```
def two_pi():
    from math import pi
    return 2 * pi
```

Comment: What I want is `mymodule` to expose only certain functionality. It's not cool that the user could see every imported module inside `mymodule`. There must be a workaround to achive this :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would want to do that, since removing `pi` from `mymodule` will cause `two_pi()` not to work.
Anyhow, you can use `del(mymodule.pi)` to remove the object `pi` from `mymodule`.

You might want to pass `pi` as a parameter to the function, and of course you can do `from mymodule import two_pi`

Answer (score 0):

You may use two files like: two_pi.py and __two_pi_impl.py

**__two_pi_impl.py**:

```
from math import pi as __pi

def two_pi():
    return 2 * __pi
```

**two_pi.py**:

```
import __two_pi_impl

two_pi = __two_pi_impl.two_pi
```

Then:

```
>>> import two_pi
>>> dir(two_pi)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__two_pi_impl', 'two_pi']
```